# Generate session ID in Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I have to create load test using JMeter. The simplest version of test should create HTTP POST request with certain content. The URL should look like:

```
/myapp/SESSION-ID/SEQIENCE
```

Where
`SESSION-ID` is custom UUID
`SEQUENCE` - sequence number (1, 2, 3, ...) into the session.

I have defined HTTP request in JMeter like following:

```
/myapp/${sessionid}/${__counter(true)}
```

My problem is to generate the session ID. I want to use different session for each user, but it should be the same for all hits of specific user. Sounds simple.

I added User defined variable to my thread group: `sessionid=${__UUID}`.
This generates global UUID for *all* requests and threads. I tried to wrap User defined variables configuration element together with HTTP request sampler with simple controller to reduce the scope of variable visibility but it did not help.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my test plan. Some elements on the top show my attempts to achieve the aim described above and are disabled.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.8" jmeter="2.13 r1665067">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Cligate1" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">My first attempt to run simple test again cligate</stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">true</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
          <elementProp name="host" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">host</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">localhost</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
          <elementProp name="port" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">port</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">8080</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
        </collectionProp>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thick client POST screenshot thread pool" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">10</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1443949496000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1443949496000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <CSVDataSet guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="CSVDataSet" testname="SingleSessionId per file" enabled="false">
          <stringProp name="delimiter">,</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="fileEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="filename">sessionid${__threadNum}.csv</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="quotedData">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="recycle">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="shareMode">shareMode.all</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="stopThread">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="variableNames">sessionid</stringProp>
        </CSVDataSet>
        <hashTree/>
        <CSVDataSet guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="CSVDataSet" testname="File with all session IDs" enabled="false">
          <stringProp name="delimiter">,</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="fileEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="filename">sessionids.csv</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="quotedData">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="recycle">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="shareMode">shareMode.all</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="stopThread">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="variableNames">sessionid</stringProp>
        </CSVDataSet>
        <hashTree/>
        <Arguments guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="false">
          <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
            <elementProp name="sessionid" elementType="Argument">
              <stringProp name="Argument.name">sessionid</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__UUID}</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
          </collectionProp>
        </Arguments>
        <hashTree/>
        <UserParameters guiclass="UserParametersGui" testclass="UserParameters" testname="User Parameters" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="UserParameters.names">
            <stringProp name="607797809">sessionid</stringProp>
          </collectionProp>
          <collectionProp name="UserParameters.thread_values">
            <collectionProp name="-1753070663">
              <stringProp name="187832203">${__UUID}</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
            <collectionProp name="2010322626">
              <stringProp name="97314">bbb</stringProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </collectionProp>
          <boolProp name="UserParameters.per_iteration">false</boolProp>
        </UserParameters>
        <hashTree/>
        <BeanShellPreProcessor guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="BeanShellPreProcessor" testname="BeanShell PreProcessor" enabled="false">
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="parameters"></stringProp>
          <boolProp name="resetInterpreter">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="script">String uuid = &quot;${__UUID}&quot;; //assuming you have removed the user defined variables
//String uuid = &quot;${user.defined.UUID}&quot; + (ctx.getThreadNum() + 1);
String sessionid = uuid + (ctx.getThreadNum() + 1);
vars.put(&quot;sessionid&quot;, uuid);</stringProp>
        </BeanShellPreProcessor>
        <hashTree/>
        <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
            <elementProp name="" elementType="Header">
              <stringProp name="Header.name">content-type</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="Header.value">image/jpeg</stringProp>
            </elementProp>
          </collectionProp>
        </HeaderManager>
        <hashTree/>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="Metadata" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">${host}</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">${port}</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout">100</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout">1000</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding">UTF-8</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/thickclient/screenshot/3F2504E0-4F89-41D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301/${sessionid}/${__counter(true)}</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">POST</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Files" elementType="HTTPFileArgs">
            <collectionProp name="HTTPFileArgs.files">
              <elementProp name="C:\progs\apache-jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\clarisite\screenshot.jpg" elementType="HTTPFileArg">
                <stringProp name="File.path">C:\progs\apache-jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\clarisite\screenshot.jpg</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="File.paramname"></stringProp>
                <stringProp name="File.mimetype">image/jpeg</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">Empty valid JSON</stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree/>
        <kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector guiclass="kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.HitsPerSecondGui" testclass="kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector" testname="jp@gc - Hits per Second" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>false</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
          <longProp name="interval_grouping">1000</longProp>
          <boolProp name="graph_aggregated">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="include_sample_labels"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="exclude_sample_labels"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="start_offset"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="end_offset"></stringProp>
          <boolProp name="include_checkbox_state">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="exclude_checkbox_state">false</boolProp>
        </kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter where you place the `User Defined Variables` config element. They get initialized first. The value will be same for all the threads.

To create thread/user specific UUID, add a beanshell preprocessor under the first HTTP request with below code.

```
String uuid = "${user.defined.UUID}" + (ctx.getThreadNum() + 1); //appending thread number to make it unique for the user.
vars.put("UUID", uuid);
```

user.defined.UUID is the variable name you had used for UUID in your user defined variable. If the sessionid is the variable name, It will be

```
String uuid = "${sessionid}" + (ctx.getThreadNum() + 1); //appending thread number to make it unique for the user.
vars.put("UUID", uuid);
```

Use `${UUID}` throughout the test to access the unique sessionID created for the user.

---

After getting some idea on your test plan,

```
Thread Group
      Once Only Controller
          Beanshell Sampler
                 String uuid = "${__UUID}";
                 vars.put("UUID", uuid);
      HTTP Request 1
      HTTP Request 2
      .. etc
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it creates unique UUID for each hit, not for whole session. What's wrong?

Comment: Please try the second approach. `"${user.defined.UUID}" + (ctx.getThreadNum() + 1);` - It should work. Or please post your test plan.

Comment: `"${__UUID}" + (ctx.getThreadNum() + 1)` works exactly as `"${__UUID}"`. Attempt to use `user.defined.UUID` does not work at all. The server does not receive any request although Jmeter does not complain as well. I tried to use `System.out.println()` in script to print the resulting ID but nothing is printed. Is there any way to debug the test?

Comment: Please see the updated answer. First of all i did not know your test plan design. Now i know what you are trying to do. Try this - `"${user.defined.UUID}" + (ctx.getThreadNum() + 1); `   in this case `user.defined.UUID` is the  user defined variable you had used for UUID. If the  `sessionid` is the variable - use `"${sessionid}" +  (ctx.getThreadNum() + 1)`

Comment: Now I understood your idea. It is fine but I need a valid UUID because then it is being parsed, so any suffix is unacceptable :(. I can however replace the last character of UUID with the thread number as you recommended. This will work, but I wonder if there is cleaner solution.

Comment: @AlexR, Do you set any loop count? For each iteration, you need a different UUID?

Comment: If you need different UUID for each iteration, remove the once only controller from the update answer. Use Beanshell sampler under thread group. If you need same UUID specific to user for all iteration, use the once only controller approach.

Comment: No, I need 1 ID per thread. This is a kind of user session. This is the problem: user defined variables are global among threads, user parameters are different for each hit.

Comment: I have just attached my test plan to my question. Could you please take a look? I am sorry to ask to this favor but I spent toooo muuuch time trying to solve this problem.

Comment: @AlexR, I see that you set thread count as 1 & the loop count as 10. it means 1 user hits the same url 10 times again and again. In this case, for each time, you need different sessionID?  I totally understand you need 1 sessionid for 1 user. But do you also need 1 sessionif for 1 iteration? Because answer will slightly vary based on your requirement.